# Error while printing 2 arrays with sort selection method

Tags: c++

Ive been working with this project for school to leanr about the sorting and searching methos like quicksort, bubblesort, etc.
I started working one cpp file per method. Everythind almost works fine, but when the program is printing the info, the first column (words) prints 0x70fc90 instead the words.

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int buscarpeq (int[],int);  
int main ()  
{  
    string busquedasFrecuentes[20] ={"2d arrays","matrices","algoritmos", "arrays c++", "C++ Multidimensional", "initialize 2d array", "center elements","2d array as element", "matriz bidimensional","too many initializers","0x6ffdf0 error c++","c++ beginners","error initializers char","combining 2d array","random number list generator","multidimensional arrays","c++ matriz 2 arrays","llenar matriz letras","multidimensional char array","c++ matrix bidimensional"};
    int frecuencia [] = {152,5,5,842,476,438,65,152,148,4,16,5,634,634,120,16,729,148,83,645,83,570,148,842,706,788,842,716,395,707,707,152,500,560,614,463,847,152,83,707};                
    int pos,temp,pass=0; 
     
     
    cout<<"\n\n\n Elementos a ordenar\n";  
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  
    {  
        cout<<busquedasFrecuentes[i]<<"\t";  
    }  
    cout<<"\n\n\n Elementos a ordenar\n";  
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  
    {  
        cout<<frecuencia[i]<<"\t";  
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  
    {  
        pos = buscarpeq (frecuencia,i);  
        temp = frecuencia[i];  
        frecuencia[i]=frecuencia[pos];  
        frecuencia[pos] = temp; 
        pass++;
    }  
    cout<<"\n\n\n Lista ordenada...\n";  
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  
    {  
        cout << "    "  << busquedasFrecuentes << "     " <<frecuencia[i]<< sizeof(20) << endl;
    } 
    cout<<"\n\nNumero de ciclos usados para ordenar la lista: "<<pass<<endl;
    return 0;  
}  
int buscarpeq(int frecuencia[],int i)  
{  
    int ele_small,position,j; //declaramos variables elementos menores y posiciones 
    ele_small = frecuencia[i];  
    position = i;  
    for(j=i+1;j<20;j++)  
    {  
        if(frecuencia[j]<ele_small)  
        {  
            ele_small = frecuencia[j];  
            position=j;  
        }  
    }  
    return position;  
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to append `[i]` on `busquedasFrecuentes`

Instead of this:

```
cout << "    "  << busquedasFrecuentes << "     " <<frecuencia[i]<< sizeof(20) << endl;
```

This:

```
cout << "    "  << busquedasFrecuentes[i] << "     " <<frecuencia[i]<< sizeof(20) << endl;
```

Also, I'm not sure why you want to print `sizeof(20)` at the end of each string.  That will always resolve to the number `4`(or more precisely, the size of an integer on your platform) getting printed on the end of each line.

Comment: i nee to use an array for 20 values, frecuencias and busquedasfrecuentes. Must simulate most recent searches i made and the times i searched a term on the web.

Comment: @Acidous - that does not make sense.  What do you intend `sizeof(20)` to literally print on the console?